# What is the general Taylor Expansion for the following function of a function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, brownian-motion

guys.

I am stuck with a general form of Taylor Expansion of following function, which is defined as a function of a function: 
$$F(X(t+h))-F(X(t))=[X(t+h)-X(t)]\frac{dF}{dX}(X(t))+\\\frac{1}{2}[X(t+h)-X(t)]^2\frac{d^2 F}{d X^2}(X(t))...$$
where $X(t)$ can be a function of Brownian motion, and $h$ is a small displacement in t. And the above function is given by my supervisor, so I suppose it is correct, however I am a little bit confused about the derivation procedure. I was wondering if there is any help can be provided. Many Thanks!

Comment: It is perhaps the strange notation which causes your confusion. If you write $F'$ and $F''$ for the derivatives Taylor's theorem says $F(x+v)-F(x)= vF'(x)+\frac 12 v^2 F''(x)+\ldots$. Then you replace $x$ by $X(t)$ and $v$ by $X(t+h)-X(t)$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks a lot. It solves my question.